# Why Dense SIFT produces these keypoints?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, vlfeat

I'm trying to understand how Dense SIFT works using VLFeat [documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/dsift.html) and [API](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/dsift_8h.html#a0cba85e88ae5232fe74368175a8ba510). I'm testing a 16x16 image and a 16x18 image.

This is the code that I'm using (using also OpenCV for images):

```
//supposing we have cv::Mat img
//convert it to float pointer
cv::Mat imgFloat;
img.convertTo(imgFloat, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0);
if(!imgFloat.isContinuous())
    throw std::runtime_error("imgFloat is not continous");
//stepsize=2, binsize=4
VlDsiftFilter *dsift = vl_dsift_new_basic (img.cols, img.rows, 2, 4);
vl_dsift_process (dsift, imgFloat.ptr<float>());
std::cout<<"nKeyPoints= "<<vl_dsift_get_keypoint_num(dsift)<<std::endl;
VlDsiftKeypoint const * kpts = vl_dsift_get_keypoints (dsift);
for(int i=0 ; i<vl_dsift_get_keypoint_num(dsift) ; i++)
  std::cout<<i<<": x="<<kpts[i].x<<" y="<<kpts[i].y<<std::endl;
```

Now, considering that SIFT by default use 4x4 bins, and here each bin is of size 4px, we have that our window is the whole image for the 16x16 one. Just use this image (taken from [here](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/dsift.html)) as reference:

[image]

And the keypoint position should be at the perfect center of the image, so **one** of the following options (supposing that indices start from 0):

- 7x7
- 7x8
- 8x7
- 8x8

(depending on the implementation)

**Instead this is the output** (for the 16x16):

```
nKeyPoints= 4
0: x=6 y=6
1: x=8 y=6
2: x=6 y=8
3: x=8 y=8
```

And this is for 16x18 image:

```
nKeyPoints= 6
0: x=6 y=6
1: x=8 y=6
2: x=6 y=8
3: x=8 y=8
4: x=6 y=10
5: x=8 y=10
```

Why this happens?

**UPDATE:**
Using `binsize=5` we have only one keypoint in position `x=7.5 y=7.5`

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution by myself. Keypoints are not decided so each bins is going to fit inside the image, but only it's center. Quoting the [documentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/dsift.html):

> Keypoints are sampled in such a way that the centers of the spatial
>   bins are at integer coordinates within the image boundaries. For
>   instance, the top-left bin of the top-left descriptor is centered on
>   the pixel (0,0). The bin immediately to the right at (binSizeX,0),
>   where binSizeX is a paramtere in the VlDsiftDescriptorGeometry
>   structure.

So `(0,0)` was the coordinate of the top-left bin (which center is `(2,2)` for approximation). The rest it's obvious considering DSIFT behavior.